# How do you avoid the same data in foreach, on sequential data?

Tags: php, loops, logic

This is the data now

> string(3) "3.1"
>
> string(3) "3.2"
>
> string(3) "3.3"
>
> string(3) "3.4"
>
> string(3) "3.1"
>
> string(3) "3.2"

And this is the data I want

> string(3) "3.1"
>
> string(3) "3.2"
>
> string(3) "3.3"
>
> string(3) "3.4"

stop looping here

> string(3) "3.1"
>
> string(3) "3.2"

and the following code that I made

```
<?php 
$tempData = null; 
foreach ( $nilai as $key ) : 
  if( $tempData !== $key->no_kd ) :
      echo "<pre>"; var_dump($key->no_kd); echo "</pre>";
      $tempData = $key->no_kd; 
   endif; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: This is not a laravel or codeigniter related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
<?php
$tempData = array();
foreach ($nilai as $key){
    if(!(in_array($tempData,$key->no_kd))){
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($key->no_kd); echo "</pre>";
        $tempData[] = $key->no_kd;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) Your `<?php>` end tag is wrong. 2) In the loop you assign `$tempData` a string value of `$key->no_kd`, which means that `in_array` won't work. 3) Which problem does this answer actually solve?

Comment: oops!! sorry about the wrong closing tag, was in a hurry, in the code written above, $tempData becomes an array, so you can use method array_push($tempData,$key->no_kd), to push the string to the array, so any time a new key-value is coming in, it checks the array if it already exists using in_array() method. Hope you understand now? Forgive my tag errror too.. smiles

Comment: That makes more sense, but... `$tempData = $key->no_kd;` - after the first loop, $tempData is no longer an array.

Comment: $tempData still remains an array, you are just appending the value to it. but i think this is the correct syntax $tempData[] = $key->no_kd; you can try both out though.

Comment: `$tempData[] = ...` is the correct way in this situation, yes.

Comment: so, does that fix the issues?

Comment: It fixes the records being unique problem, but simply using `array_unique` is more readable and simpler. Your solution will work though.

Comment: okay, no problem, i was wondering how array_unique will work with object values

Comment: Dang... You are correct. I was under the assumption that the array is an array of strings, so my answer is just plain wrong. Deleted my answer.